# SQL - SELECT DISTINCT WITH UNION of TWO COLUMNs and SORTED or GROUPED BY most occurances of common items in SQL or possibly PHP?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have two columns with comma-separated keywords like so:

Hobbies & Activities

Typical entries are like so:

### Hobbies

1 Gardening, Cars, Cards 
2 Running
3 Running, Birdwatching, Cars
4 Football, Birds
5 Cars, Running
6 Football
7 Gardening, Cars, Sports, Eating

### Activities

1 Sports, Birds, Walking
2 Cars
3 Football, Gardening
4 Cards, Hiking, Cleaning, Eating
5 (empty)
6 Cars, Gardening
7 Birdwatching, Gymnastics, Football

I am creating a drop-down menu where I want to group similar activities next to each other.

So first I want to combine both Hobbies and Activities and then display the distinct combinations sorted by most similar.

TOGETHER THEY ARE...
1 Gardening, Cars, Cards, Sports, Birds, Walking
2 Running, Cars
3 Running, Birdwatching, Cars, Football, Gardening
4 Football, Birds, Cards, Hiking, Cleaning, Eating
5 Cars, Running
6 Football, Cars, Gardening
7 Birdwatching, Gardening, Cars, Sports, Eating, Gymnastics, Football

AND SORTED/REARRANGED so that the items are counted and grouped by most amount of shared occurrences of the greatest number of keywords… (SOMEWHAT) LIKE SO:

Cars, Running (most occurrences in the distinctness)
Cars, Football, Birdwatching, Gardening, Sports, Eating, Gymnastics
Cars, Football, Running, Gardening, Birdwatching
Cars, Football, Gardening
Cars, Gardening, Cards, Sports, Birds, Walking
Football, Birds, Cards, Hiking, Cleaning, Eating

So far I have this...

"SELECT DISTINCT Hobbies FROM interests UNION SELECT DISTINCT Activities FROM interests" as my sql query.  If possible I'd like to do the sorting in the SQL query but I'm also open to a solution in php juggling around the results as an array.  Any solutions?

Comment: Don't store lists of things in a SQL database.  You should have one row per activity and per hobby.

Comment: That's a good reminder for others but In my case I can't change it, only concatate, join, etc.